# How to refer to a particular key in array using a variable name in react?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to fetch the dev or stage key from the array inside the map function based on a declared variable called "abc". instead of {data.dev}, i want to make it like {data.abc} some thing like that
This might be easy but since i am new, not able to figure out

```
  const data = [
    { id: 1, name: "John Doe", dev: "new", stage: "new" },
    { id: 2, name: "Victor Wayne", dev: "old", stage: "old" },
    { id: 3, name: "Jane Doe", dev: "freq", stage: "old" },
  ];

const abc='dev';
  return (
    <div className="users">
      {data.map((data) => (
        <div className="user">{data.abc}</div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: I don't fully understand the question. Each object in you array has several keys which you could directly use inside your `map` function. You said you wanted to use `data.name` instead of `data.dev`, which you can certainly do. What are you trying to output?

Comment: basically want based on name variable(which will be the key) i should be able to pull the value. my bad, let me change the variable name from name to abc

Comment: Then you can do `data[abc]`

Comment: you mean {data.[abc]} ?

Comment: In JavaScript, you could use dot notation (`.`) or square bracket notation (`[]`) to access properties of something (e.g. `person.name` or `person[0]`). While `[]` is most commonly used for array indices, you could use it for object keys. This [MDN doc entry](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#computed_property_names) and [this blog article](https://www.samanthaming.com/tidbits/37-dynamic-property-name-with-es6/) might be useful for you.

Comment: got it worked well

Answer (score 1):

To access an attribute via your variable `abc` you can do :

```
data[abc]
```